# What is this separation property of locales called

Tags: separation-axioms, locales

Trying to come up with a point-free formulation of the $T_1$ axiom I thought of the following condition on a frame/locale $L$:

$$\forall U \in L \, . \, U \wedge \bigwedge \{ V \in L : U \vee V = \top \} = \bot$$

It turns out that this condition is weaker than $T_1$ for spatial locales since it holds eg for $T_1$ spaces with non-$T_1$ sobrification like $\mathbb N$ with the cofinite topology, but at least it seems to exclude non-trivial Alexandroff locales.

Does anybody know what this condition is called?

Comment: I haven't dived into it, but there is a whole book called "Separation in Point-Free Topology" by Picado and Pultr. I'm not sure, but it may be in there. Have you looked?

Comment: No I didn't know the book, thanks for the hint! I know the "Frames and Locales" book by the same authors, but haven't looked to carefully there either to be honest.